# How to create a output in matrix form for the below code snippet using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
Channel_list=['Retail' 'Hotel']
Region=['Other' 'Lisbon' 'Oporto']
temp=0
rows=[]
column=[]
for ele1 in Channel_list:
    for ele2 in Region:
        for i in WS_Customer.columns[3:]:
            temp=temp+WS_Customer[i].where(WS_Customer['Region']==ele2 ).where(WS_Customer['Channel']==ele1).mean()
        column.append(temp)
column
```

Output of the above will be like

```
[47004.971428571414,
 94142.24920634918,
 138138.98604845445,
 165352.62111954446,
 191426.21433988342,
 217110.142911312]
```

but i need to create a 2x3 matrix(table) with columns as Channel_list and Row as Region.
Can someone help me to create this.

Comment: You will probably get better results if you convert `WS_Customer` directly into the table that you want.

Comment: @DYZ  Your answer helps to create a dataframe thanks!!
But the output is not as expected,  the mean value has not been place in the correct  position. all the values are mixed up.

Comment: Please elaborate: show the expected output.

Comment: @DYZ , thanks !!. i made small changes to data-frame creation it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table = np.array(column).reshape((len(Region), -1))
pd.DataFrame(table, index=Region, columns=Channel_list)
#                Other         Lisbon         Oporto
#Retail   47004.971429   94142.249206  138138.986048
#Hotel   165352.621120  191426.214340  217110.142911
```

And I am almost sure you mixed up Region and Channel_list names.